# Reduction from permanent to $(0,1)$-permanent and implication of $P \ne NP$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matrices, permanent

[Valiant](http://www.cs.bu.edu/faculty/gacs/courses/cs535/papers/Valiant_permanent.pdf)
shows reduction from counting the solutions of CNF formula $F$,$\#SAT(F)$ 
to computing permanent where $ Perm(A)= 4^{t(F)}\cdot \#SAT(F)$
for certain efficiently computable $t(F)$ and matrix $A$ with entries from
$\{-1,0,1,2,3\}$.

$F$ is unsatisfiable iff $Perm(A)=0$.

The permanent of the adjacency matrix of digraph
counts cycle covers and is #P-complete.

The decision problem "Is the permanent of (0,1) matrix zero"
is in $P$ since finding cycle cover is in $P$.

$P \ne NP$ implies there is no reduction from permanent to
$(0,1)$-permanent which maps $0 \mapsto 0$ (since UNSAT will be in $P$).

> Is it possible to unconditionally show such reduction doesn't exist?

The paper [Zero-One Permanent is #P -Complete, A Simpler Proof](http://people.csail.mit.edu/shaih/pubs/01perm.pdf) 
appears to show the reduction chain
$$
\text{IntPerm} \propto \text{NoNegPerm} \propto \text{2PowersPerm} \propto \text{0/1-Perm}
$$
while the permanent value is preserved along the chain.

Comment: No, because the nonexistence of such a reduction implies $\#\mathrm P\ne\mathrm{FP}$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thank you. Isn't the second paper example of such reduction?

Comment: No, the reduction in Section 5.1 clearly does not preserve 0.

Comment: Working backwards in the chain which step doesn't preserve 0? (Except possibly the first step all others preserve the permanent and in the first step 0 is preserved by mod AFAICT).

Comment: There is only one step (the first one) in the one-paragraph Section 5.1, so I don’t understand what can be unclear about it. The step maps an integer matrix of permanent 0 to a non-negative integer matrix whose permanent is a huge multiple of $Q$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek from another paper p. 2: However, Ben-Dor and Halevi [3] showed the following reduction chain:IntPerm ∝ NoNegPerm ∝ 2PowersPerm ∝ 0/1-Perm whereof the permanent value is preserved along the chain. http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.4124v1

Comment: Well, it is not, so your other paper is being sloppy. This is not a research-level question, but a basic confusion.

Comment: I think an explanation of some of the terms used would be helpful.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek isnt #P is not FP conjectured?

Comment: Conjectured. Not unconditionally known. The question is about the latter.